# SQL Server 17, database migration, function for setting identity in primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, database-migration

I have two twin databases and want to migrate one into another. For that I would like to have a written function so that primary key can be set by utils function. I did already by using UI in SQL Server, but that is tiresome, as there are many tables to repeat that process. Utils function would be setting identity before migrating table and then removing it after job is done.
For example:

`insert into TABLE 
(colum_names)
select column_names
from TABLE`

Before and after I would like to set and remove identity automatically stead doing this: [image: no identity]

[image: identity set]

I know there are ways around this with recreating tables, but for obvious reasons(query time, server load) I do not want to do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding, you are using an external utility to perform this migration. In that case, you can execute the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[YourTable] ON;` statement in a command prior to your migration steps.

For example, with C#:

```
using(SqlConnection myConn= new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[YourTable] ON;";
    //Migration steps here...
    cmd.CommandText += "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[YourTable] OFF;";
}
```

EDIT:

#### The below is actually incorrect! I overlooked that IDENTITY_INSERT can only be set for a SINGLE table per SESSION. [See MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql)

As per a the commented suggestion by @benjamin moskovits to use the undocumented `sp_msforeachtable`, while this would work to SET IDENTITY_INSERT for each table in your database, this approach is nevertheless a bit of a sledgehammer which may have unintended consequences depending on the specifics of your migration pattern.

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ? ON;'
```

Comment: You can't have identity insert on for more than 1 table at a time. As such, your sp_msforeachtable will not work. And in your first suggestion you need to add setting IDENTITY_INSERT OFF for the table.

Comment: @Sean Lange, absolutely correct and an oversight on my part. As for SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF, this is also true (in that the change must be reverted per table before moving on), and while implied, explicitly including it in the snippet  makes a for a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something to each table in a database you can use the 'unsupported' but very widely used and available in almost every version of SQL Server,  sp_msforeachtable to execute something....

```
exec   sp_msforeachtable 'select count(*) ''?'' from ?'
```

will give you a list of every table in a database and the number of rows it contains.